# DVI not working on lock window or terminal

Tags: display, release-hera, greeter

I have a Asus monitor connected to my desktop computer. The screen resolution is 1920 x 1080 and it's connected with a DVI cable.

Everything works fine. When a power on the computer, I can see the login screen.
But if I use Win + L to lock the screen, or if I switch between terminal (CTRL + ALT + F1 / F2...), the screen powers off and shows the message: No DVI signal.

However, it keeps running on the background. If I carefully type my password, I can log in. Or if I swith again to desktop mode (CTRL + ALT + F7) I can see again my screen.

My video card is "NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce 210]" on a i5-3470. I'm using Hera (5.1.3)
No problems so far with it, besides these two weird things.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I just realized that if I log off (CTRL + ALT + SUPR), it works fine. Just lock screen and terminal.

Comment: I have a very similar issue! Although in my case, I do get a lock screen but heavily pixelated and without a background. Mouse cursor goes missing too.